# Navigation Bar on Modal View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a view controller that executed by a modal view (no Navigation Controller connected). I want to have a Navigation Bar on top and be able to change the buttons and title dynamically depending on what the user has selected on the view controller.

I have read that you can set the View Controllers Simulated Metrics to include either a Translucent or Opaque Navigation Bar.

However, after I select this and add a navigation item to it, I can't get it to show the buttons or title and also don't know how to reference it in code.

Can anyone help walk me through it?

Comment: Just wondering. If you want a navigation bar on top how come you don't embed the VC you are displaying modally in a navigation controller?  Otherwise you will need to add a UINavigationBar to your VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulated metrics are a design aid to help in laying out your views; the navigation bar you add that way isn't actually added to your controller at run time. You need to drag out a navigation bar from the object list, and add it to your controller's view.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Do I add a navigation bar first and then navigation item, or just navigation item?

Comment: @lr100 Just drag out the navigation bar. It will already contain a navigation item.

Comment: Thanks so much. Got it working and have the text of the back button changing based on user selection in the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Simulated Metrics is only to simulate, nothing is changed on your app. If you need a Navigation Bar create it programatically or drag out a navigation bar from the object list.